# Why is Aurelia looking in the wrong place for it's files?

Tags: typescript, components, aurelia

Iv'e decided to have a go at building an app using Aurelia, and on the whole I really like what I see.

However, I'm having severe problems trying to use the built in functionality that comes with the framework.

After 2 days of wrestling with package managers and config files, I've finally gotten my build (Typescript) to recognise that I have the aurelia-http-client library installed, but I cannot for the life of me get "au build" to look in the correct place for it (Well not without specifying the full path manually anyway)

My Component looks as follows:

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';

export class Stanoxtable {

  public getData(){

    alert("About to get data");

    let client = new HttpClient();

    client.get('http://localhost/corpus.json')
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
    });

  }

}
```

I have the following in my config.js file:

```
...
    paths: {
        "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
        "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
    },

    map: {
        "aurelia-http-client": "npm:aurelia-http-client@1.0.3",
...
```

I also have the following in package.json:

```
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "aurelia-cli": "^0.23.0",
    "aurelia-http-client": "^1.0.3",
...
  },
  "jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "aurelia-http-client": "npm:aurelia-http-client@^1.0.3"
    },
...
```

I have the physical files in my npm node_modules directory:

[image: Dir showing files]

And yet when I run

```
au build
```

All I get is this:

[image: Output from "au build"]

If I Put the FULL path in my component template EG:

```
import {HttpClient} from 'd:/aurtest2/aurelia-app/node_modules/aurelia-http-client/dist/aurelia-http-client';
```

The build then finds the file, but I get some weird parsing errors:

[image: Build output 2]

I have absolutely no idea what to do or try next, and could use some help from the aurelia experts out there.

Thanks
Shawty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Aurelia CLI serves up everything from bundles that are defined in the `aurelia_project\aurelia.json` file. You need to add `aurelia-http-client` to the `vendor-bundle` section of the `aurelia.json` file.

Work is happening currently that will automate this so that you will be able to run something like `au install aurelia-http-client` and the CLI will modify the `aurelia.json` file for you, but for now you have to modify it by hand.

Don't quote me on the configuration, but it will probably look like this:

```
{
  "name": "aurelia-http-client",
  "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-http-client/dist/amd",
  "main": "aurelia-http-client"
}
```

Comment: Wait, I'm confused now. Why do you have both a config.js and a aurelia_project folder?

Comment: I have no idea why I have both, Iv'e been trying different things for 2 days, from running all sorts of bizzare command lines, to editing all sorts of different files.

Comment: However... I knew I couldn't sleep unless I tried this, so I did.... AND IT WORKS.  My Faith in Aurelia is restored :-)

Comment: Now all I have to do is deal with the CORS / Headers problem, but that's for tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @Ashley Grant , i found out why I have 'config.js' and the aurelia project folder.  When I created my project I did so using "au new myproject" after that was done I then used "jspm install aurelia-http-client" to install the http client.  This asked me a bunch of questions (Most of which I didn't know what they where for) so I just went with the defaults, and that added the config file among other things.  Using NPM directly appears not to add this extra stuff.

Comment: Correct. You should delete the jspm_packages folder and the config.js file. When you're using the Aurelia CLI, you don't use JSPM for anything.

Comment: Thanks, yea I figured that already, installed my deps using NPM instead.